# Why does the verb "succeed" change to "successor" as a noun?

Tags: morphology

Can someone explain the why the verb **succeed** changes to **successor** as a noun and not **succeeder**?

Why the double s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It comes from Latin *successor*, which means roughly the same. The verb comes from *succed-o*, which also means roughly the same.

The root of the Latin verbal stem ***ced***- ("move away, cede") is the Proto-Indo-European root `*ke-`, "here, this" (deictic/pronominal stem), plus `*s(e)d-`, "sit, set, settle" (compound `*k̂e-zd-ō`)—so says the Oxford Latin Dictionary (1982): Pokorny and Ernout (1959) are unclear.

The prefix *sub-*, "from under", is added to form the meaning "to go sit/move from under" for *succedo*, if you will forgive me this awkward translation. It is a phonological rule in Latin that *-bc-* is normally assimilated into *-cc-*.

The supine stem of a Latin verb—the stem used to make past participles—is normally formed by adding *-t-* to the verbal stem: `*cedt-.` Phonology demands that *-dt*- (and *-tt-*) at the end of supine stems normally change into *-ss-*, hence the supine stem ***success-.*** The past participle is *successus*, roughly "succeeded".

The suffix *-or* is used in Latin to make an agent out of a verbal stem, just as in English *-or* and *-er*: hence Latin *successor*, "successor".

In English, we sometimes borrow words from Latin directly, or from Latin through French, like *successor*, while at other times we only borrow the verb and make our own agent word, like *revoker* (instead of *revocator*). But we usually use the Latin noun if you also use the Latin verb: *proceed, processor; permit, permission, etc. etc.;* sometimes we use both, as in *merge, merger, immersion*.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: Obrigado!

Comment: @Ceberus Graag gedaan

Comment: Minor point, but cedere does not come from *sed, but rather *ked.  The only way it could come from *sed is if it had prefix before a zero-grade form of *sed, i.e.: *ke-sd > L *ked.  Even then, I think we'd have a double d rather than a single one.

Comment: @siride: Ack, I accidentally simplified beyond reason. This online resource from the Univ. of Texas, which is based on Pokorny, says it only comes from [*sed-](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1658.html), not [*ke-/*ko-](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0990.html). I was surprised myself, but I just copied it. However, the (probably more reliable) Pokorny on my PC says it comes from *ke-, as you say, plus possibly *do- "give", under these respective lemmata. But under *sed- it says it may come from *ke- plus the zero grade of *sed-: *k̂e-zd-ō (pp. 884-887). ...

Comment: ... Ernout (1959) says the etymology of *cedo* is unknown. So the ce- part comes from *ke- "here, this" without a doubt. That sounds far more logical than this silly *sed-. I will never trust that source from the University of Texas again! I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @siride: Oh, it turns out that Pokorny probably had the nonce-imperative cĕdo in mind for the roots `*ke-` plus deictic/demonstrative `*do-` (= as in *endo-*, Eng. *to* ;  ≠ `*do-` "give"), while the regular verb cēdo comes from the roots `*ke-` plus `*sed-`. At least this is the etymology given by the Oxford Latin Dictionary (1982).

Comment: @Cerberus: that etymology is satisfying (well, more satisfying).  I am enlightened.

Comment: @siride: It was an honour. Incidentally, you might be interested in joining the new Stackexchange site Linguistics, if you haven't committed yet. It will be launched in a few days: if you're quick, you can be there in the closed/private beta. In case you didn't know, you're never obligated to post anything. Your comments will no doubt be appreciated. [Linguistics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics)